# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 / CORS: HTTP Headers not being sent with request

Tags: http, angular, cors, ionic2

I'm working on a project using Ionic 2 (2.0.0-beta.10). I try to pass an authorization token with the request. However the header is not being sent. Also other headers I tried to pass with the request are not being sent.

```js
let url = 'http://www.example.com/savedata';
let data = JSON.stringify({ email: 'test@test.com', password: '123456' });

let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "tokenContent");

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(url, data, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

                console.log("it worked");

}, error => {
                console.log("Oooops!");
});
```

My REST API receives this request with the following headers:

```
Host:               www.example.com 
Connection:         keep-alive  
Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST    
Origin:             http://evil.com/    
User-Agent:         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36   
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, content-type 
Accept:             */* 
Referer:            http://localhost:8100/?restart=794567   
Accept-Encoding:        gzip, deflate, sdch 
Accept-Language:        en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The data (body) comes in correct, only the headers problem I cannot resolve.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to pass headers like this `this.http.post(url, data, {headers:headers})....`

Comment: I tried to do this, but the headers I receive in the REST API upon sending the request are the following:  Host www.example.com 
Connection keep-alive 
Content-Length 45 
Origin http://evil.com/ 
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36 
Content-Type text/plain 
Accept */* 
Referer http://localhost:8100/?restart=794567 
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate 
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: ok, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301878/ionic-2-angular-2-http-headers-are-not-being-sent-along-with-the-request

Comment: Thanks, I did already read this issue. However none of the answers actually describes the solution of this issue. According to Bala Abhinav, he managed to solve the problem, but he didn't mention how.... 
"The problem was a CORS issue. It is solved now. thanks. – Bala Abhinav"

Comment: Are you setting what headers are authorized in your REST API? `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request

Comment: @GwenTiana — The solution is that the server has to respond with permission. The specifics of that depend on what server and/or server side language you are using.

Comment: did you solve this ? @GwenTiana  . This not a CORS issue. I have two apps, one with ionic 1 and other with ionic 2.  Same http call (same endpoint) works on ionic v1 app , but headers are not sent in ionic 2 app. Same http call works on Angular 2 web app too.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

This question has an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286959/4119650

`Headers.append()` does not update the object, it returns a clone of it. By instantiating the Headers object and then calling `headers.append()`, the result of that `append` isn't being used.
Instead, you may need to do this:

`headers: Headers = new Headers().append('Content-Type', 'application/json').append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "tokenContent");`

`Headers` is deprecated anyway, and should be replaced with `HttpHeaders` and `HttpClient`.
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders
https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http). It is easiest and latest one.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
...
...

postData() {
   const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    });

   let url = 'http://www.example.com/savedata';
   let data = JSON.stringify({ email: 'test@test.com', password: '123456' });


   this.http.post(url, data, { headers: httpHeaders, observe: 'response'}).subscribe(data => {    
                console.log("it worked");    
   }, error => {
                console.log("Oooops!");
   }); // Here you don't need to use map().
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are calling REST API (example.com in your example) that is located on a different domain from your Angular 2 / Ionic app ( evil.com in your example), then you need to configure REST API server to return this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://evil.com
```

Which will allow the browser to send async HTTP requests from evil.com host to the rest api server.

It is done by enabling CORS on the rest api server, you can read about it a bit more.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Several libraries for the backend that enable cross origin requests:

https://github.com/expressjs/cors - NodeJS/Express

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors/ - Python cors library for Flask

and the list continues for almost any other backend framework.

Answer (score -1):

Stringify JSON this not realy working at all  times.
First you need to convert your JSON data to StringQuery to be understand by the server properly and much faster way.

```
public StringQuery(jsonString) {
        return Object.keys(jsonString).map(function (key) {
          return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonString[key]);
        }).join('&');
      }
```

then you make your post function or method

```
public post(){
let url = 'http://www.example.com/savedata';
let data = this.StringQuery({ email: 'test@test.com', password: '123456' })




    let headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "tokenContent");

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post(url, data, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

                    console.log("it worked");

    }, error => {
                    console.log("Oooops!");
    });
}
```

I use this code too and get success post request.

Answer (score -1):

For sending and receiving you might be using one server ex:Nginx
Config file in sites-enabled for backend ,there you have to add   **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * or http://localhost** that can be helpful.